# Calculating doubles by dates with format timeIntervalSince1970 from 2 different dictionaries

Tags: swift, date, dictionary, sum

I have 2 dictionaries:

`bought: [Int64: [String:String]]` is when the user bought the cryptocurrency

readable dictionary:

```
2018-12-04 17:41:48
["amount": "5000.0", "symbol": "MOBI"]
2018-12-06 13:52:44
["amount": "1.5", "symbol": "ETH"]
2018-12-06 13:53:47
["amount": "200.0", "symbol": "XRP"]
2018-12-08 12:01:04
["amount": "2.0", "symbol": "ETH"]
```

original dictionary :

```
[1543945308:["amount": "5000.0", "symbol": "MOBI"],
1544104364:["amount": "1.5", "symbol": "ETH"],
1544104427:["amount": "200.0", "symbol": "XRP"],
1544270464:["amount": "2.0", "symbol": "ETH"]]
```

`pricesForPreviousDays:[Int64:[String:Double]]` are the prices of the cryptocurrencies taken after adding them in bought

readable dictionary:

```
2018-12-04 23:59:59
["MOBI": 0.01481]
2018-12-05 23:59:59 
["MOBI": 0.01243]
2018-12-06 23:59:59 
["MOBI": 0.01179, "XRP": 0.3074, "ETH": 90.43]
2018-12-07 23:59:59 
["MOBI": 0.01114, "XRP": 0.3023, "ETH": 93.61]
2018-12-08 23:59:59 
["MOBI": 0.01125, "XRP": 0.3074, "ETH": 91.44]
```

original dictionary:

```
[1543967999:["MOBI": 0.01481],
1544054399:["MOBI": 0.01243],
1544140799:["MOBI": 0.01179, "XRP": 0.3074, "ETH": 90.43],
1544227199:["MOBI": 0.01114, "XRP": 0.3023, "ETH": 93.61],
1544313599:["MOBI": 0.01125, "XRP": 0.3074, "ETH": 91.44]]
```

I have to calculate the amount of the money that user have for the day.
Example dictionary `moneyForTheDay[Int64:Double]` where Int64 is the end of the day (I have Date extension which gets the end of the day) and Double is the whole amount of the money that day.

So for the first day(2018-12-04)the code have to calculate `MOBI amount * MOBI price = 5000 * 0.01481 = ?`

For the third day(2018-12-06) the user added XRP and ETH so the code have to calculate `MOBI amount * MOBI price + XRP amount * XRP price + ETH amount * ETH price`

**Attention:** For the fifth day(2018-12-08) user bought another 2 ETH so the code have to get ETH from 2018-12-06 and make the sum automatically `1.5+2 = 3.5`, so the ETH amount for 2018-12-08 have to be 3.5 and the formula is the same `MOBI amount * MOBI price + XRP amount * XRP price + ETH amount * ETH price`

I've tried with:

```
var moneyForDay:[Int64:Double] = [:]
        for key in pricesForPreviousDays.keys{
            for key2 in bought.keys{
                if(Int64(Date(timeIntervalSince1970: TimeInterval(key2)).startOfDay.timeIntervalSince1970)<key){
                    if(pricesForPreviousDays[key]![bought[key2]!["symbol"]!] != nil){
                        if(moneyForDay[key] == nil){
                            moneyForDay[key] = Double(bought[key2]!["amount"]!)! * Double(pricesForPreviousDays[key]![bought[key2]!["symbol"]!]!)
                        }else{
                            var previousMoney = moneyForDay[key]!
                            previousMoney += Double(bought[key2]!["amount"]!)! * Double(pricesForPreviousDays[key]![bought[key2]!["symbol"]!]!)
                            moneyForDay[key] = previousMoney
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

but it's not calculating properly and I don't know why...

Comment: Hint: The time is in UTC. Look into timezones

Comment: of course it is in UTC, because the website that I took the information, about the prices is in UTC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have decided to work with the dates as a simple formatted string here for simple comparison of dates. For this I have a simple utility function to convert the int date

```
func parseToDateString(_ intDate: Int64) -> String {
    let formatter = ISO8601DateFormatter()
    formatter.formatOptions = [.withFullDate]
    let date = Date(timeIntervalSince1970: TimeInterval(intDate))
    return formatter.string(from: date)
}
```

For the actual calculations I decided to first create a kind of event chain so I know which crypto currencies are owned for each date and then I loop over the keys `pricesForPreviousDays` in date order and look up owned currencies and prices in the price collection to calculate daily values for each day a currency is owned which is indirectly defined by the date range in the price array.

```
typealias CryptoTuple = (symbol: String, amount: Double)
var cryptosPerDay = [String: [CryptoTuple]]()

var prev = ""
bought.keys.sorted(by: <).forEach( { key in
    let date = parseToDateString(key)
    if let buy = bought[key], let symbol = buy["symbol"], let amountStr = buy["amount"], let amount = Double(amountStr) {
        if prev != date {
            cryptosPerDay[date] = [(symbol, amount)]
            if let old = cryptosPerDay[prev] {
                cryptosPerDay[date]?.append(contentsOf: old)
            }
            prev = date
        } else  {
            cryptosPerDay[date]?.append((symbol, amount))
        }
    }
})

var last = [CryptoTuple]()
pricesForPreviousDays.keys.sorted(by: <).forEach( { intDate in
    let date = parseToDateString(intDate)
    let position = cryptosPerDay[date] ?? last

    var totalPerDay = 0.0
    position.forEach( {
        let symbol = $0.symbol
        let amount = $0.amount

        if let item = pricesForPreviousDays.first(where: { parseToDateString($0.key) == date && $0.value.keys.contains(symbol) }) {
            totalPerDay += amount * item.value[symbol]!
        }
    })
    last = position
    print("\(date) - \(totalPerDay)")
})
```

Output is

> 2018-12-04 - 74.05
>   2018-12-05 - 62.15
>   2018-12-06 - 256.07500000000005
>   2018-12-07 - 256.575
>   2018-12-08 - 437.77

Comment: Where is the output for 2018-12-05 and 2018-12-07 ? How much money the user have these days ?

Comment: @BogdanBogdanov I have update my solution to loop over the keys in `pricesForPreviousDays`

Comment: Why you are using sorted and why I get
`2019-02-01 - 0.0
2019-02-02 - 0.0
2019-02-03 - 0.0
2019-02-04 - 0.0
2019-02-05 - 0.0
2019-02-06 - 284.19
2019-02-07 - 283.889
2019-02-08 - 323.657
2019-02-09 - 325.54299999999995
2019-02-10 - 335.138`

When sorted is < and when is > the result is:
`2019-02-10 - 0.0
2019-02-09 - 0.0
2019-02-08 - 0.0
2019-02-07 - 0.0
2019-02-06 - 284.19
2019-02-05 - 169.846
2019-02-04 - 169.606
2019-02-03 - 170.79799999999997
2019-02-02 - 176.41500000000002
2019-02-01 - 171.836`
SORTED in pricesForPreviousDays and how to fix it ?

Comment: @BogdanBogdanov I am using sorted to make sure all dates in the range gets properly calcualted. I don't understand what your asking really, I see that you have different totals depending on how you sort but I don't know what you have changed in the code. Do you really need to change the code, can't you re-sort afterwards?

Comment: I found another problem in the code:
If this is bought: ` [1549424985: ["amount": "10.0", "symbol": "XRP"], 1546531017: ["amount": "1.0", "symbol": "ETH"], 1549424153: ["amount": "50.0", "symbol": "EOS"], 1546531031: ["symbol": "XRP", "amount": "200.0"]]` The output of cryptosPerDay is: `["2019-02-06": [(symbol: "EOS", amount: 50.0), (symbol: "ETH", amount: 1.0), (symbol: "XRP", amount: 200.0), (symbol: "XRP", amount: 10.0)], "2019-01-03": [(symbol: "ETH", amount: 1.0), (symbol: "XRP", amount: 200.0)]]` Why it's repeating some symbols ?