# Swift - Grouping data by days in dictionary

Tags: swift, dictionary, grouping

This is the dictionary:

`[1549424985: ["amount": "10.0", "symbol": "XRP"], 1546531017: ["amount": "1.0", "symbol": "ETH"], 1549424153: ["amount": "50.0", "symbol": "EOS"], 1546531031: ["amount": "200.0", "symbol": "XRP"]]`

```
typealias CryptoTuple = (symbol: String, amount: Double)
var cryptosPerDay = [String: [CryptoTuple]]()
var prev = ""
groupedData.keys.sorted(by: <).forEach( { key in
    let date = parseToDateString(key)
    if let buy = groupedData[key], let symbol = buy["symbol"], let amountStr = buy["amount"], let amount = Double(amountStr) {
        if prev != date {
            cryptosPerDay[date] = [(symbol, amount)]
            if let old = cryptosPerDay[prev] {
                cryptosPerDay[date]?.append(contentsOf: old)
            }
            prev = date
        } else {
            cryptosPerDay[date]?.append((symbol, amount))
        }
    }
})
```

This is the code provided from my previous question's answer: [Calculating doubles by dates with format timeIntervalSince1970 from 2 different dictionaries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53753804/calculating-doubles-by-dates-with-format-timeintervalsince1970-from-2-different)

but this code returns me repeated values
print(cryptosPerDay)
`["2019-02-06": [(symbol: "EOS", amount: 50.0), (symbol: "ETH", amount: 1.0), (symbol: "XRP", amount: 200.0), (symbol: "XRP", amount: 10.0)], "2019-01-03": [(symbol: "ETH", amount: 1.0), (symbol: "XRP", amount: 200.0)]]`

How to fix it ?

Comment: What does fix it mean? Totally unclear what the desired outcome is. And what is parseToDateString? Show your actual code. (And why are you using tuples?)

Answer (score 1):

The answer in the other question is far from ideal. Here is a much simpler way to convert your `[Int64: [String: String]]` to be grouped by day (using `Date`, not `String`).

```
let cryptoData: [Int64: [String: String]] = [
    1549424985: ["amount": "10.0", "symbol": "XRP"],
    1546531017: ["amount": "1.0", "symbol": "ETH"],
    1549424153: ["amount": "50.0", "symbol": "EOS"],
    1546531031: ["amount": "200.0", "symbol": "XRP"],
    ]

let cryptosPerDay = cryptoData.reduce(into: [Date: [[String: String]]]()) { (result, element) in
    result[Calendar.current.startOfDay(for: Date(timeIntervalSince1970: TimeInterval(element.key))), default: []].append(element.value)
}

print(cryptosPerDay)
```

Output:

> [2019-01-03 07:00:00 +0000: [["amount": "1.0", "symbol": "ETH"], ["symbol": "XRP", "amount": "200.0"]], 2019-02-05 07:00:00 +0000: [["symbol": "EOS", "amount": "50.0"], ["amount": "10.0", "symbol": "XRP"]]]

Keep in mind that the `Date` keys represent midnight local time. Your results will be slightly different depending on your timezone.

Or with your `CryptoTuple`:

```
let cryptosPerDay = cryptoData.reduce(into: [Date: [CryptoTuple]]()) { (result, keyvalue) in
    result[Calendar.current.startOfDay(for: Date(timeIntervalSince1970: TimeInterval(keyvalue.key))), default: []].append((symbol: keyvalue.value["symbol"]!, amount: Double(keyvalue.value["amount"]!)!))
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's unclear what the goal is, but here's a way to do what I *think* you are trying to do. Notice the use of structs rather than tuples:

```
let d = [ // your data
    1549424985: ["amount": "10.0", "symbol": "XRP"],
    1546531017: ["amount": "1.0", "symbol": "ETH"],
    1549424153: ["amount": "50.0", "symbol": "EOS"],
    1546531031: ["amount": "200.0", "symbol": "XRP"]
]
struct Trade {
    let amount:Double
    let symbol:String
}
var result = [String:[Trade]]()
for key in d.keys {
    let date = Date(timeIntervalSince1970: Double(key))
    let f = DateFormatter()
    f.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
    let dayString = f.string(from: date)
    let val = d[key] as! [String:String]
    let trade = Trade(
        amount: Double(val["amount"]!)!,
        symbol: val["symbol"]!
    )
    result[dayString, default:[]].append(trade)
}
```

After that, `result` is:

```
["2019-02-06": [Trade(amount: 10.0, symbol: "XRP"), Trade(amount: 50.0, symbol: "EOS")], 
 "2019-01-04": [Trade(amount: 1.0, symbol: "ETH"), Trade(amount: 200.0, symbol: "XRP")]]
```

...which seems to be the "right" answer. Personally, I think it's silly to use date strings this way; it would be better to use actual dates. In that case, the last part could be rewritten as:

```
var result = [Date:[Trade]]()
for key in d.keys {
    let date = Date(timeIntervalSince1970: Double(key))
    let day = Calendar(identifier: .gregorian).startOfDay(for: date)
    let val = d[key] as! [String:String]
    let trade = Trade(
        amount: Double(val["amount"]!)!,
        symbol: val["symbol"]!
    )
    result[day, default:[]].append(trade)
}
```

Comment: Didn't know dictionaries had a `subscript(_:default:)` method. Good to know!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Dictionary(grouping:by:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/dictionary/3127163-init) to group the elements of any sequence including a dictionary.

```
let result:[String:[[String:String]]] = Dictionary(grouping: cryptoData) { parseToDateString($0.key) }.mapValues { $0.compactMap({ $0.value }) }
print(result)
```

> ["2019-01-03": [["amount": "200.0", "symbol": "XRP"], ["amount":
>   "1.0", "symbol": "ETH"]],
>
> "2019-02-06": [["amount": "10.0", "symbol": "XRP"], ["amount": "50.0", "symbol": "EOS"]]]

---

**Using Tuple**

```
let result:[String:[CryptoTuple]] = Dictionary(grouping: cryptoData) { parseToDateString($0.key) }.mapValues { $0.compactMap({
    if let symbol = $0.value["symbol"], let amountStr = $0.value["amount"], let amount = Double(amountStr) {
        return (symbol, amount)
    } else { return nil }
}) }
```

---

**Using Struct**

```
struct Crypto {
    var symbol: String
    var amount: Double
    init?(_ dict:[String: String]) {
        if let symbol = dict["symbol"], let amountStr = dict["amount"], let amount = Double(amountStr) {
            self.symbol = symbol
            self.amount = amount
        } else {
            return nil
        }
    }
}
let result:[String:[Crypto]] = Dictionary(grouping: cryptoData) { parseToDateString($0.key) }.mapValues { $0.compactMap({ Crypto($0.value) }) }
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to first check if there is already a tuple in the array for a given symbol and if so merge it and the new one rather than appending the new tuple.

Change the `else` clause at the end in the loop to

```
if let index = cryptosPerDay[date]?.firstIndex(where: {$0.symbol == symbol}) {
    let total = (cryptosPerDay[date]?[index].amount ?? 0) + amount
    cryptosPerDay[date]?[index] = (symbol, total)
} else {
    cryptosPerDay[date]?.append((symbol, amount))
}
```